# Page title does not appear in ViewPager after setting it from the viewpager adapter

Tags: java, android

the title not appear in the PagerTabStrip after i set it from the adapter

this is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager pager ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this));
    }

}
```

this is my layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/titlepage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"

        />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and this is the adapter

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm , Context ctxt) {
    super(fm);

}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return MyFragment.newInstance(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position) {

    return "title" + position ;
}
```

and this is the theme used in application :-

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

the result :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0GoQ.png)

as u see in above picture there is no title appear in viewpager even i set the title in getPageTitle method , can someone tell me what is the error that prevent me to add the title in viewpager ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/Parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Its my code, you can customize it according to your convenience.

Comment: i add the above code and inside viewpager i add PagerTabStrip but still the title not appear as seen in pic http://pictub.club/image/FjIE2

Answer (score 1):

`PagerTabStrip` gets ignored by Google a lot. You may wish to consider switching to some other `ViewPager` tab indicator.

If your `compileSdkVersion` is 23, make sure that you are using the latest version of the v23 Android support libraries. Right now, that is `23.4.0`. So, for example, you might have a dependency on `support-v4:23.4.0`. The problem that you are seeing [was fixed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183127).

If your `compileSdkVersion` is 24, keep an eye on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213359), as there seems to be a new bug.

Comment: thank you , at least i know now the problem not from my code

Comment: Just one addition for convenience: if your ``compileSdkVersion`` is 24, there is a workaround in that isse: ``((ViewPager.LayoutParams) tabStrip.getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;`` (you need to ``findViewById`` it)